# I "wouldn't / won't" recommend it to others. - is the "would" the hypothetical use?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

What is the difference between using "wouldn't" and "won't" in Example 1?

Does "wouldn't" sound softer and maybe more indefinite? Is it related to the hypothetical use of "would"?

**Example 1**

> I have finished the book. I **wouldn't** recommend it to others.

> I have finished the book. I **won't** recommend it to others.

---

Is the "would" in Example 2 the hypothetical use of would? Does it suggest that what has been said is kind of imaginary or hypothetical?

**Example 2**

> Your son is doing well in school. He **would** become a successful businessman in the future.

> Your son is doing well in school. He **will** become a successful businessman in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Would" or "Wouldn't" in these contexts does mark a conditional or hypothetical clause. The condition is apparently "if someone asked me to recommend it"

By making something hypothetical you make it more *tentative*, and that has the effect of softening the statement. It is therefore more polite.

In example two, would also marks a conditional phrase, which is odd as I can't work out what the condition is. There is no need to be tentative. But you might want to express uncertainty.  It would be more natural to use a modal like "could" or "might" instead of "would".